# Can Kconfig language install on mac OS

Tags: linux, macos, makefile, kbuild

I have to do a project by using Kconfig but it seems this stuff can just work on Mac OS. I don't know if there is a tool that install Kconfig on MAC OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if it could run with macports or homebrew but you can always rely on virtual box to make a virtual linux machine

Comment: I have check the software on mac port but there is nothing :(